# use django-allauth to request and store oauth credentials only

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-allauth

i have a django project using django-allauth.

I want to add the ability for users to provide their consent for my web app to interface with the google api.
I think django-allauth has this all neatly packaged away but the docs and the implementation are (appropriately) targeted towards login authentication.

What i want to do is:

1. display a page where users can click a button that says "Connect my google account"
2. have users provide their consent on the google page
3. process the oauthcall back using allauth internals

Is there an example of this somewhere? I tried searching but i think i don't know what keywords to search for.

Any assistance apprecieated

Comment: One of the views (for managing accounts) has links for connecting your account to a social provider. Maybe looking at the source code for that would help.

Comment: thanks. i did. It was confusing so i decided to post the question first and then dig more. Experimenting a little i think i can just call the relevant view and it will automatically redirect the user with required info. I will update later with what i find. have to setup the google account properly and stuff. It won't let me test in my private network so i have to find a public facing one.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?